# How to inspect swift function implementations

Tags: swift, xcode

How can I look behind the scenes? For **example** I would like to know more about the `isEqual` function ... `Command+Click` -> `Jump to Definition` does not show how this function work.

```swift
let pi : Double = 3.14159265359
pi.isEqual(3.14159265359)
```

Comment: You should jump to the definition by right click on isEqual then select Jumb to the definition.

Comment: that's what I did and like @EmilioPelaez wrote I can see the definition (function signature) as well as some comments but the Implementation is missing...

Answer (score 2):

If the code is in a compiled framework, like `Foundation` or `UIKit` for example, Xcode will take you to the declaration of the function, where you'll be able to see the function signature and maybe some comments about it, but not the full code becase since the code has already been compiled, Xcode doesn't have access to it.

Swift is open source, you can go to the repository and see how it's implemented. I think this includes most of `Foundation`, but it won't include Apple's frameworks like `UIKit`, `SwiftUI`, etc.

Comment: as I read [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/floatingpoint/1846385-isequal) the `isEqual` function for example is Part of the **Swift Standard Library** but its hard to find more information as all google results will point to the apple documentation

Comment: As I said, if you want to see the implementation you have to go to the Swift repository: https://github.com/apple/swift. That said, it won't be easy to navigate, it will be lower level, and you probably won't find it a lot more useful than just reading what the documentation describes.